# JAX-WS SOAP Client Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am hoping you can help me.

I am trying to create a Java SOAP client using JAX-WS.

I have imported all of the Web Service functions using wsimport,
for this I had to supply an auth file using -Xauthfile, the auth file contained the following:

http://username:password@server.com:80/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl

I have imported all of the classes into eclipse and I am trying to call the MathService add function using the following code:

```
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import com.ptc.jws.service.org.myorg.mathservice.MathServiceImpl;
import com.ptc.jws.service.org.myorg.mathservice.MathServiceImplService;

public class ClientStart {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

 MathServiceImplService service = new MathServiceImplService();
 MathServiceImpl port = service.getMathServiceImplPort();

 // Configure service endpoint (override defined one of the WSDL) 
 BindingProvider binding = (BindingProvider) port;
 binding.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService");


 // Add HTTP Basic Authentification credentials to this request      
 binding.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "username");   
 binding.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
 port.add(1, 1);

}

}
```

I have tried with/without overriding the service endpoint

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to  access the WSDL at: http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl. It failed with: 
Got Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl while opening stream from http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl.
```

I also get this error:

```
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EncryptedParts" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Mar 01, 2016 4:29:13 PM     [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
```

The MathServiceImpl.java file is as follows:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "MathServiceImplService", targetNamespace = "http://MathService.myorg.org.service.jws.ptc.com/", wsdlLocation = "http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl")
public class MathServiceImplService extends Service
{

private final static URL MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://MathService.myorg.org.service.jws.ptc.com/", "MathServiceImplService");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}

public MathServiceImplService() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public MathServiceImplService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public MathServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public MathServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public MathServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public MathServiceImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns MathServiceImpl
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "MathServiceImplPort")
public MathServiceImpl getMathServiceImplPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://MathService.myorg.org.service.jws.ptc.com/", "MathServiceImplPort"), MathServiceImpl.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns MathServiceImpl
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "MathServiceImplPort")
public MathServiceImpl getMathServiceImplPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://MathService.myorg.org.service.jws.ptc.com/", "MathServiceImplPort"), MathServiceImpl.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
        throw MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    }
    return MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Tim

Comment: Has the problem been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 401 HTTP response seems to come from the application that serves the WSDL definition itself. I think it's best (when possible) to download the WSDL and bundle it in the application resources.

Then you have to change the URL in the JAX-WS generated file (likely `MathServiceImplService.java`) from `http://server.com/xxx.wsdl` to some URL like

```
MathServiceImplService.class.getResource("/path/to/wsdl.wsdl");
```

Comment: Hello Raffaele,

Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. I have downloaded the wsdl file to my application resource. Could you explain which parts of MathServiceImplService.java I need to modify? I have added it to the original question. Thanks soo much. Tim

Comment: See the static initializer where `new URL("http://server.com/Windchill/servlet/MathService?wsdl");`

Comment: I have changed this to:
'MATHSERVICEIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = MathServiceImplService.class.getResource("MathService.wsdl");' and I still get the same error! I have added some more detailed stacktrace to the original post!

Comment: Perhaps there is more to the problem? The WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion error?

Answer (score 2):

I used `wsimport` to generate codes and faced with the same problem. `Authenticator` works for me. Add the below code before init the service.

```
   Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("<UserName>", "<Password>".toCharArray());
        }
    });

   MathServiceImplService service = new MathServiceImplService();
   ...
```

Comment: same problem, works for me too. Better than trying to add HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS on request context.